# Spring 3.0 RESTful Controller Fails on Redirect

Tags: spring, rest, redirect, spring-mvc

I am setting up a simple RESTful controller for a Todo resource with an XML representation. It all works great - until I try to redirect. For example, when I `POST` a new Todo and attempt to redirect to its new URL (for example `/todos/5`, I get the following error:

```
Error 500 Unable to locate object to be marshalled in model: {}
```

I do know the `POST` worked because I can manually go to the new URL (`/todos/5`) and see the newly created resource. Its only when trying to redirect that I get the failure. I know in my example I could just return the newly created Todo object, but I have other cases where a redirect makes sense. The error looks like a marshaling problem, but like I said, it only rears itself when I add redirects to my RESTful methods, and does not occur if manually hitting the URL I am redirecting to.

A snippet of the code:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/todos")
public class TodoController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/{id}", method=GET)
    public Todo getTodo(@PathVariable long id) {
        return todoRepository.findById(id);
    }

    @RequestMapping(method=POST)
    public String newTodo(@RequestBody Todo todo) {
        todoRepository.save(todo); // generates and sets the ID on the todo object
        return "redirect:/todos/" + todo.getId();
    }

    ... more methods ...

    public void setTodoRepository(TodoRepository todoRepository) {
        this.todoRepository = todoRepository;
    }

    private TodoRepository todoRepository;
}
```

Can you spot what I am missing? I am suspecting it may have something to do with returning a redirect string - perhaps instead of it triggering a redirect it is actually being passed to the XML marshaling view used by my view resolver (not shown - but typical of all the online examples), and JAXB (the configured OXM tool) doesn't know what to do with it. Just a guess...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the 500 happening inside `newTodo` or `getTodo`?

Comment: Somewhere in between - the body of `getTodo` is never reached, while `newTodo` successfully saves the new resource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happend because `redirect:` prefix is handled by `InternalResourceViewResolver` (actually, by `UrlBasedViewResolver`). So, if you don't have `InternalResourceViewResolver` or your request doesn't get into it during view resolution process, redirect is not handled.

To solve it, you can either return a `RedirectView` from your controller method, or add a custom view resolver for handling redirects:

```
public class RedirectViewResolver implements ViewResolver, Ordered {
    private int order = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

    public View resolveViewName(String viewName, Locale arg1) throws Exception {
        if (viewName.startsWith(UrlBasedViewResolver.REDIRECT_URL_PREFIX)) {
            String redirectUrl = viewName.substring(UrlBasedViewResolver.REDIRECT_URL_PREFIX.length());
            return new RedirectView(redirectUrl, true);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public int getOrder() {
        return order;
    }

    public void setOrder(int order) {
        this.order = order;
    }
}
```

Comment: With the `RedirectViewResolver` I get a code 302 indicating the "browser" should redirect. Thanks!