# Spring MVC: Why do I need to (and how do I?) provide a mapping for a JSP view?

Tags: spring-mvc

I'm attempting to have a controller method return a ModelAndView object which uses a JSP as the view.  The application context configuration for the ViewResolver:

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" /> 
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" /> 
</bean>
```

The JSP I'm using for the view is located as /WEB-INF/jsp/error.jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" 
         contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" 
         pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>Unexpected Error</h1>

        ${message}

    </body>
</html>
```

In my controller I resolve the View and return the ModelAndView:

```
ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("error");
modelAndView.addObject("message", errorMessage);
return modelAndView;
```

I can step through the code and all looks good until the ModelAndView is returned, at which point I see this in the log:

```
DEBUG 2011-11-03 15:33:52,262 (org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView:236) - Forwarding to resource [/WEB-INF/jsp/error.jsp] in InternalResourceView 'error'
DEBUG 2011-11-03 15:33:52,262 (org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet:845) - DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' determining Last-Modified value for [/nacem-rest/WEB-INF/jsp/error.jsp]
DEBUG 2011-11-03 15:33:52,263 (org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet:853) - No handler found in getLastModified
DEBUG 2011-11-03 15:33:52,263 (org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet:693) - DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/nacem-rest/WEB-INF/jsp/error.jsp]
WARN  2011-11-03 15:33:52,263 (org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound:965) - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/nacem-rest/WEB-INF/jsp/error.jsp] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
DEBUG 2011-11-03 15:33:52,264 (org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet:674) - Successfully completed request
```

So it looks like I also need to have some sort of mapping for JSP files, even though the web.xml specifies all URLs should be handled by the DispatcherServlet:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/application-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Apparently I need to add a request mapping for this JSP file into the controller, although I'm not sure why or how.  The View backed by the JSP is a JstlView and I assumed that Spring knows how to deal with that and see to it that it's rendered in the browser.  But maybe not, and I need to add some code to make this happen?  It looks like there's a redirection going on and I need to catch the request again by another mapped controller method, and within that method go about rendering the JSP.  Is this the case?  I don't see anything at all in the reference documents which explain how to do this, maybe someone can point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance for your comments, suggestions, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the difference is, but looking at the equivalent in one of my (working) apps, I use `InternalResourceViewResolver` instead of `UrlBasedViewResolver`. For example:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
  <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
  <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
```

Also, less likely, my web.xml has a different pattern (`/` instead of `/*`):

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>WEB-INF/spring/*.spring.xml</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Everything else you have looks pretty much the same.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion; unfortunately I've tried this with no difference in results.  It seems like the view is being resolved to the JSP with no issues, but instead of the view being rendered the request is being forwarded to the URL corresponding to the view's JSP page, and at that point instead of it being rendered the request is picked up again by the DispatcherServlet which has no mapping for the URL.

Comment: Hmmm. Are you doing a redirect? If so, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3155775/spring-3-0-restful-controller-fails-on-redirect) that I asked and had answered.

Comment: No I am not redirecting anywhere within my code, so I'm not sure where the forward is happening, shortcutting the call to renderMergedOutputModel() which I assumed should be called on the View as part of the ModelAndView returned by the controller method (in this case a JSP page for error messages).